# How to use jQuery inside a WP thickbox

Tags: wordpress, jquery, plugins, thickbox

I'm creating a Wordpress plugin wich adds a metabox to post edit page.
In this metabox there is a link to open a page in a native thickbox (ajax content and NOT into iframe)

In this opened content I would like to use jQuery of 'parent' page (WP admin page) but I got a "jQuery is undefined"...

Any idea ?

thank's :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the error and what code resulted in the error?

Comment: As it is, your Question is purely theoretical... What's the code that opens the thickbox? Where's the content of this TB is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

...and $j is your jQuery object